# Using `HttpSendRequestW` to send length 30 string, but the Dart server only receive 8

Tags: winapi, dart

Here is the client:

```
string magicX = "123456789009876543211234567890";
int request[];
ArrayResize(request,StringLen(magicX));
char charArray[];
StringToCharArray(magicX,charArray,0,StringLen(magicX));
for(i = 0; i < ArraySize(charArray); i++)
  {
   request[i] = (int)charArray[i];
  }
int arrSize = ArraySize(request);
if(!HttpSendRequestW(hReq, "", 0, request, arrSize))
  {
   InternetCloseHandle(hReq);
   InternetCloseHandle(hConn);
   InternetCloseHandle(hIntrn);
   return (false);
  }
```

Here is the server (Dart):

```
HttpServer server = await HttpServer.bind
    InternetAddress.anyIPv4,
    webServerPort,
);

await for (HttpRequest request in server) {
     aLog.i('Server receive a ${request.headers.contentLength.toString()} header');
     String aString = await utf8.decodeStream(request.asBroadcastStream());
     print('Server receive aString: ${aString}');
     aLog.i('Server receive url: ${request.uri}');
}
```

Here is the result:

```
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Server receive a 30 header
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Server receive aString: 12345678
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
│ Server receive url: /HelloWorld
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

As you can see the length is match, but the actual result is incorrect, any ideas? Thanks.

More info:
I use postman to post a long text to server as follow:
[image]

The Dart server can read all the text, but the `HttpSendRequestW` can't. Thanks.

Comment: You are sending an array of `int`, not an array of `char`, so I'm guessing that every character actually occupies 4 bytes (32 bit integer), so you are sending: `'1', 0, 0, 0, '2', 0, 0, 0, `3`, 0, 0, 0 ... '8', 0, 0`. And then the server log does not show the NUL characters.

Comment: `char charArray[];` - What programming language is that?